# Show selected options on top in ng-select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using ng-select package to show dropdowns. I want to show the selected options on top of the dropdown list. Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: I doubt that ng-select provides the feature. Something you can do in component is by tracking when the option is selected, then sort the options by setting the selected options as first item. And this implementation could cost the performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, when you select the option you can push it into an array
2. So now you have two arrays, the selected options array, and the original data array
3. lets say they are originalArr and selectedArr
4. inside ng-select ng-option

> ```
>    <ng-option *ngFor="let item of selectedArr"> {{ item }} </ng-option>
>     <ng-container  *ngFor="let item of originalArr">
>       <ng-option *ngIf="!selectedArr.includes(item)"> {{ item }} </ng-option>
>     </ng-container>
> ```

5. So, here you display the selected items, and prevent selected items from
   appearing again in the dropdown